# Authorise.net showing error for test webhook

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

[image: Error message]

Can you please tell me what went wrong? I am testing Webhook and it's showing this error. Also I used the `https://apitest.authorize.net/rest/v1/notifications` to get the notification details. and its returning

```
"notificationId": "92222984-0593-4d3f-815f-c6aa6954525e", 
"deliveryStatus": "RetryPending", 
"eventType": "net.authorize.payment.authcapture.created", 
"eventDate": "2023-08-22T16:03:11.133", 
"webhookId": "06a407f7-17d2-467e-b6ab-c0e37e79eb79"
```

Comment: Well which bit of the error don't you understand? There was a problem connecting to your site. Is that URL publicly visible on the internet? I tried to connect to it and it also failed. My guess is that this is a URL within your own local network and therefore is not visible to outside services. That's why the authorise.net service cannot connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

`http://testpayment.test` doesn’t exist.

The name suggests it is a domain name that is used internally by your network.

The third-party service doesn’t have access to your internal network (neither HTTP nor DNS).

You need to use a **public facing** URL.